# Cannot compile JSP file with JavaMail API

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jakarta-mail

I am struggling to find a code that works in sending emails using JSP.

I have an html form to gather the text body of the message, and then code shoudl have the rest of the information in order to reduce the user´s work at the time of sending notifications out to the team.....

The JSP code is as follows, and I keep getting error messages saying that Session cannot be resolved to a type, Message cannot be resolved to a type, MimeMessage cannot be resolved to a type, etc......

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*, javax.mail.*, javax.mail.internet.*" %>

<%

// SMTP Authentication settings
String host = "smtp.e-tools.com.ve";
String user = "info@e-tools.com.ve";
String pass = "password";

// E-Mail settings
String to = "shee_mass@hotmail.com";
String from = "info@e-tools.com.ve";
String subject = "E-tools Notification - New Document/Comment to see";
String mesg = request.getParameter("smsInput");

boolean sessionDebug = false;
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.host", host);
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");

Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
mailSession.setDebug(sessionDebug);

// Create message to send
Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
msg.setSubject(subject);
msg.setSentDate(new Date());
msg.setText(messageText);

// Send message
Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect(host, user, user);
transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
transport.close();

%>
```

Answer (score 2):

Getting *cannot be resolved to a type* JSP compilation errors while imports are seemingly fine can also just mean that those classes are simply not present in the classpath. It's like as getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` during runtime in normal Java.

Fact is, in contrary to real Java EE containers such as Glassfish, a simple servletcontainer such as Tomcat doesn't ship with JavaMail. You need to ensure that you've added it yourself by [downloading](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html) the JavaMail JARs and dropping them in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`.

Writing raw Java code in JSP files instead of Java classes is not funny.

Comment: I have downloaded the jars into the lib folder in Web-Inf, but I still get the same errors....not sure what else to do....

Comment: The page import looks fine (I'll ignore the possibility that you're not running the code you think you're running). But `/Web-Inf/lib` is invalid. Java is case sensitive. It should be `/WEB-INF/lib`. You need to have placed *at least* the from the downloaded ZIP file extracted `mail.jar` file in there (and thus not the whole downloaded ZIP file or something). If you're running Java 1.5, you need `activation.jar` as well (as per the download link in my answer).

Comment: Thanks BalusC, but all of that have been done.... the case sensitive issue was just me typing here as I am desperate.... I have all the jars in the lib folder and I have activation.jar too....

Comment: Are you using an IDE with JSP auto completion and assistance? For example Eclipse? Its JSP editor should have jerked with something like "Import `javax.mail` cannot be resolved". If it didn't and your JSP code was free of IDE validation errors, then perhaps your runtime classpath is after all just one big mess.

Comment: No I am not, I think I need to find a different way of doing this, I thought it was easier...but it is cosumming a lot of my time!...

Comment: Writing Java code in JSP files instead of Java classes is indeed a nightmare. I'm honestly happy that you finally *experience* it by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Sheeyla, I had the exact same problem.  I am using Tomcat6.  The issue is that Tomcat6 doesn't like the mail.jar folder being in the WEB-INF/lib folder and insists on it being a globally shared jar to work.  Put the mail.jar in the CATALINA_HOME/lib folder (/usr/share/tomcat6/lib by default), delete it from the WEB-INF/lib folder, restart Tomcat6 and it'll work.  You don't need the activation.jar since you're most likely on java 1.6 either so you can get rid of that too.